# How to calculate the spaces between texts according to rectangle width?

Tags: lua, directx, draw

I would like to ask you, how to calculate the text position, more like the spaces between texts.

Ive got an array with texts text1, text2, text3, text4... And I can call a function to get the length of the text in pixels and I also know the length of the rectangle and I would like to calculate the spaces between each text to entirely fill the rectangle and only keep 10px from both sides.

Function to get the text length is dxGetTextWidth and rectangle width is specified in a variable called rWidth.

How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

A Text Justification Algorithm can do what your looking for.
https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse221/200910/Projects/Markov/justification.html

Here is an example based on your question:

```
local output_width = 0
local line_width = box.rWidth() - 20 --10px from each side

local line = {}

for text in ipairs(texts) do
    text_width = text.dxGetTextWidth()

    if (output_width + text_width <= line_width) then
        output_width = output_width + text_width
        line[#line + 1] = text

    else
        remaining_space = line_width - output_width
        space_width = remaining_space / #line       --space evenly spread over words in the line
        for text in ipairs(line) do
            --now add the space between each word
        end
    end
end
```